# How to Install The NetGear Wireless Adapter (N600 WNDA3100v3) on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, adapter, netgear

I just bought this wireless adapter to replace my tethered connection. One problem - It's meant for windows. I have tried many tutorials, but the connection just won't show, and I can't get this thing working. Can you help me? Thanks in advance. This is NOT the same as the WNA3100, or the WNDA3100 v1 or v2.